# Python gdal.translate doesn't write the output file

Tags: qgis, python, raster, gdal, rgb

I am very new with gdal and python in general, therefore pardon my simple question.
I have a geotiff (single band, black and white) that I want to change from grayscale to RGBA (becasue I want to use gdal.DEMProcessingOptions to add color-relief).
I am using the following script but I don't get any output file in the folder. Do I have to specify somewhere that I want to write the output?

```
gray = gdal.Open("input.tif")
rgba= "output.tif"
colour=gdal.TranslateOptions(rgbExpand="rgba")
gdal.Translate(rgba, gray, options=colour)
```

Comment: Try `gdal.UseExceptions()` at the beginning of your code so gdal raises an exception if there's an error instead of just returning `None` https://gdal.org/api/python_gotchas.html#python-bindings-do-not-raise-exceptions-unless-you-explicitly-call-useexceptions. Then add the exception text to your question.

Comment: Line `colour=gdal.TranslateOptions(rgbExpand="rgba")` looks suspicious. Where did you find documentation to use that?

Comment: @ user2856 Thanks, I have added gdal.UseExceptions() and now I get this error: RuntimeError: Error : band 1 has no color table

Comment: @user30184 I have just followed (hopefully correctly) the instructions in help(gdal.Translate): Translate(destName, srcDS, **kwargs)
    Convert a dataset.
    Arguments are :
      destName --- Output dataset name
      srcDS --- a Dataset object or a filename
    Keyword arguments are :
      options --- return of gdal.TranslateOptions(), string or array of strings
      other keywords arguments of gdal.TranslateOptions()
    If options is provided as a gdal.TranslateOptions() object, other keywords are igno

Comment: How about the value use used `rgbExpand="rgba"`. Are you sure that it is using correct syntax? I do not know, just asking.

Comment: I think so. Using help(gdal.TranslateOptions) I get this:

TranslateOptions(options=[], format=None, outputType=0, bandList=None, maskBand=None, width=0, height=0, widthPct=0.0, heightPct=0.0, xRes=0.0, yRes=0.0, creationOptions=None, srcWin=None, projWin=None, projWinSRS=None, strict=False, unscale=False, scaleParams=None, exponents=None, outputBounds=None, metadataOptions=None, outputSRS=None, GCPs=None, noData=None, rgbExpand=None, stats=False, rat=True, resampleAlg=None, callback=None, callback_data=None)
    
rgbExpand --- Color palette expansion mode: "gray", "rgb", "rgba"